# TypeScript type not inferred as expected

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I have a use case where I want to define a set of filters as an object. I want to know which filters there are exactly and have auto completion for it, but in the generic handling of the filters, it can be just be any key as long as it adheres to certain types for their values. I thought to use generics and extends, which works to a certain degree, but there are a few situations where it does not unify based on the type it is extending like I would expect it too. Here is a simplified example of what I attempted and what goes wrong:

```js
type Foo = { [key: string]: boolean | string[] }
class Bar<F extends Foo> {
  constructor(public arg: F) {}
}
const bar = new Bar({ foo: false, bar: [] })
// Reported as always being false.
console.log(bar.arg.foo)
for (const n of bar.arg.bar) {
  // Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'never'. ts(2339)
  n.includes("x")
}
```

I expected it to infer `boolean` rather than `false` (for `foo`), and `string[]` rather than `never[]` (for `bar`). I assume extends does not unify the types quite as I expected. Is there a way to achieve this in TypeScript? Meaning I would get full knowledge that the instance of `Bar` has the properties `foo` and `bar`, but inside the class itself, it only knows the generic type (as in, some object, rather than knowing its specific keys).

Comment: TypeScript expects narrow types as per [ms/TS#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) (for `boolean` anyway).  You can force the compiler to compute a widened version of `F` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2E6jW) but it's somewhat unergonomic to use, at least for the implementer of `Bar`.  Does that meet your needs or are you looking for something else (and if so, can you elaborate)?

Comment: There's also [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBeznw) which describes the desired type of the `Bar` class constructor and then just asserts that a given class constructor value is assignable to it.  This one is probably nicer for users of `Bar`, but again it's not ergonomic for the implementer.

Comment: @jcalz I had kinda hoped that this was a common enough use case not to have to spell it out like that. However, it does work well, so if you put it forth as an answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by @jcalz in the comments to my question was the answer I was looking for. I ended up implementing it similarly to the example given by him:

```js
type Foo = { [key: string]: boolean | string[] }

type WidenFoo<T extends Foo> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? boolean : string[] };

class Bar<F extends Foo> {
    arg: WidenFoo<F>
    constructor(arg: F) {
        this.arg = arg as WidenFoo<F>;
    }
}
const bar = new Bar({ foo: false, bar: [] })

bar.arg.foo // boolean
bar.arg.bar // string[]

console.log(bar.arg.foo)
for (const n of bar.arg.bar) {    
    n.includes("x")
}
```

As he mentioned, per PR [ms/TS#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676), literal types will be used whenever applicable and will be as specific (narrow) as possible. AFAIK there is no way to have TypeScript widen literal types automatically, so we have to do it ourselves via `T extends Type ? Type : ...` tricks. I tried it and it works well for more complex types too, such as my use case (has recursive types and such).